# Cordova - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'ontouchend' in null"

Tags: cordova

So I am building a cordova application. I am getting this error while launching a release on Android. I do not get this bug while testing the cordova application locally with a debug release. I am not sure what is happening that is causing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'ontouchend' in null
at La (com.example:9)
at V (com.example:10)
at Ya (com.example:10)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null
at H (com.example:7)
at S (com.example:9)
at HTMLDocument.Na (com.example:12)
```

In any js that I have written I do not use an in operation on anything or have code for ontouchend.

Version of cordova
8.0.0

Version of Android
Android ^7.0.0

Any help would be great! Thanks!